# Programming style: object with passages by references or value? (c++)

Tags: c++, coding-style, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

This is a general question on programming style. Let's say I have an object `Line` which has some methods and private variables `Point point_a_` and `Point point_b_`. Let's say that at some point I need to change the position of the two points. What programming style would you prefer between the following cases? They all do the same thing (or *should* do: I didn't compile, but seems pretty straightforward).

***CASE 1***

```
Class Line {
public:
  Line(Point point_a, Point point_b) : point_a_(point_a), point_b_(point_b) {}

  void UpdatePoints(Point point_a, Point point_b) { 
    point_a_ = point_a; point_b_ = point_b;
  }

  double Distance();

private:
  Point point_a_;
  Point point_b_;
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
  Point point_a(0,0,0);
  Point point_b(1,1,1);
  Line line(point_a,point_b);
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";

  point_a.x = 1;
  line.UpdatePoints(point_a,point_b);
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";
}
```

***CASE 2***

```
Class Line {
public:
  Line(Point point_a, Point point_b) : point_a_(point_a), point_b_(point_b) {}
  Point& point_a() { return point_a_; }
  Point& point_b() { return point_b_; }
  double Distance();

private:
  Point point_a_;
  Point point_b_;
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
  Point point_a(0,0,0);
  Point point_b(1,1,1);
  Line line(point_a,point_b);
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";

  line.point_a().x = 1;
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";
}
```

***CASE 3***

```
Class Line {
public:
  Line(Point* point_a, Point* point_b) : point_a_(point_a), point_b_(point_b) {}

  double Distance();

private:
  Point* point_a_;
  Point* point_b_;
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
  Point point_a(0,0,0);
  Point point_b(1,1,1);
  Line line(&point_a,&point_b);
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";

  point_a.x = 1;
  std::cout<<line.Distance()<<"\n";
}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

[EDIT] Speed is paramount in my software!

Comment: How about public member variables?

Comment: Thanks Martinho. I want to avoid public variables. This is just a simplified example for my much more complicated software, where I always need to check inputs, so I prefer `set` and `get` methods rather than using public variables.

Comment: ok, just making sure you considered that.

Comment: This is too abstract. What does it mean to change a Line? Is it still the same line, or a new one? Is it drawn somewhere? Connected to anything?

Comment: Thanks @Bo. This is only a simplified example of my very complicated object in the software. The actual object in my problem is the same when I change it. Let's say I could have used `Person` as example, and the variable that changes is `age`.

Comment: @Enzo - That's an example of where the interface matters, and the semantics are important. I would very much like to do `me.setAge(25);` or `BankAccount.setBalance("$1M");`, but that doesn't work. Hard to say if it works for a Line. That's why it is hard to define a general rule for an abstract interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple scenario I might just use public member variables.

Otherwise I would provide getters that return a *const reference* and matching setters.

```
class Line {
public:
    Line(const Point& p1, const Point&p2) : m_p1(p1), m_p2(p2) {}

    const Point& p1() const 
    { return m_p1; }

    const Point& p2() const
    { return m_p2; }

    void setP1(const Point& p1)
    { m_p1 = p1; }

    void setP2(const Point& p2)
    { m_p2 = p2; }

private:
    Point m_p1;
    Point m_p2;
};
```

Comment: -1: Returning a reference is not a good idea.  It doesn't allow you to swap out the internal implementation.

Comment: It's a _const_ reference! If you'd change the internal implementation you would most likely update the header as well anyway. Since the reference is const you can be sure no other code modified the returned object.

Comment: Wholly disagree -- look at any well written C++ library (like boost). Const references are returned whenever it could potentially be "expensive" to return a copy. Without (me) providing an implementation for Point, you cannot make the assumption that it is incorrect

Comment: If you're happy to change the API when your internal implementation changes, then yes, I would agree with you.  Also, Google for "copy elision".

Comment: How does returning a reference imply any additional changes are necessary when your "internal implementation" changes?  Internal implementation of what exactly?  Perhaps I'm being dense here -- but given the need of an accessor function, what would you prefer be returned in this case that wouldn't require additional changes?

Comment: @Chad: The usual argument for setters and getters is that it allows you to encapsulate the internal representation.  So in a later revision, you might not have `Point` members at all (you may decide later to maintain `p1`, `direction` and `length`, for instance), but dynamically generate them when you call `get`.  Obviously, this is not possible (or at least, it's very tricky) if you are returning a reference.

Comment: Thanks @Oli for your feedback. On your last comment to Chad: I see your point, but considering that speed is paramount for me, and that the member I am actually working with might be very large, what would you prefer: do a potentially large and unnecessary copy or preserve the API?

Comment: @Enzo: *If* you're sure that you'll never change the implementation, then returning a reference is ok.  (Speed is usually not a concern, due to *copy elision*.)  But I'd question why you wouldn't just use public member variables in that case.

Comment: That's a valid point, and the code posted here (and in my answer below) assumed that points should be accessed as they are in the original post.  Also, modifying the internal implementation in such a drastic way would require significant interfaces changes, and I personally wouldn't consider the return of references a problem in the original version.

Comment: Fair point, the `get_()` methods could in theory return copies of dyanmically generated objects.

Answer (score 1):

Case three is totally out because it completely violates principles of encapsulation. Case two does as well, to a slightly lesser extent. I would prefer option one, but did you consider possibly making the points immutable and forcing you to create a new object when it changes?

Also to be pedantic if I remember correctly from many years ago, a line technically extends infinitely in both directions. You're actually representing a line *segment*.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. It actually *is* a segment, but you really *are* pedantic ;) This is a simplified version of my problem, where I have a number of other temporary variables stored in the object, so I don't want to create a new object every time.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this question @Mark. I came across a similar problem again, and found that **Case 1** is actually a case of <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection> . Do you strongly argue against it and in favour of encapsulation? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 is no better than public member variables.  In particular, it doesn't encapsulate anything.

Case 3 makes ownership of the points unclear.  Consider what happens if your points are local variables in the calling function, and then they go out of scope.  It also offers no benefits over public member variables.

So out of these three options, Case 1 is the cleanest, IMO.  Other options are:

- simply use public member variables.
- make `Line` immutable.
- use `set` and `get` functions.

Comment: Thanks @Oli. The main reason why I wouldn't want to use Case 1 or 2 is speed, which is the most important variable in my software. In Case 1 I need to do copies in the constructor, and when I update. In Case 2 I only need to do copies in the constructor. What do you think?

Comment: -1 Passing by value in this case creates redundant extra copies.

Comment: @Chad: Please Google for "copy elision".  And at any rate, the OP asked for "cleanest", not necessarily "most efficient".

Comment: As I understand it, copy elision in this particular case is not valid on (most current) conforming compilers.  In C++0x (when it is more widely supported) then copy elision in this case becomes a valid possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose either case 1 or an immutable Line class.

Case 2 allows changes to the Point objects without the knowledge of their containing line. At some point, you might need the line to know if its points have been changed.

Case 3 either makes the Line object dependent on the lifetime of the Points, or makes the Line the owner of the points, which is not clear from the API.

An immutable Line would allow you to create a new Line object with new points.

Answer (score 0):

Case 4 -- Prefer passing by const reference rather than value (or pointer):

```
class Line
{
public:
    Line(const Point& a, const Point& b) : a_(a), b_(b)
    {}

    const Point& get_a() const { return a_; }
    const Point& get_b() const { return b_; }

    void set_a(const Point& a) { a_ = a; }
    void set_b(const Point& b) { b_ = b; }

private:
    Point a_;
    Point b_
};
```

This is better in that in enforces encapsulation - the only way to change the variables held in the class after construction is a specific mutator method.

The accessors return a const reference, so they cannot be modified (copies made from these can be).

The class as a whole is made const-correct.

References are arguably better than pointers in this instance because they are guaranteed (unless you specifically break that guarantee) to not be NULL.

Comment: -1: Returning a reference is not a good idea. It doesn't allow you to swap out the internal implementation.

Comment: Wholly disagree -- look at any well written C++ library (like boost).  Const references are returned whenever it could potentially be "expensive" to return a copy.  Without (me) providing an implementation for Point, you cannot make the assumption that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider another option:

```
class Segment {
public:
    Segment(Point point_a, Point point_b);
    Point point_a() const;
    Point point_b() const;

private:
   Point point_a_;
   Point point_b_;
};


double Distance( Segment seg );

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    Point point_a(0, 0, 0);
    Point point_b(1, 1 ,1);
    Segment seg(point_a, point_b);
    std::cout << Distance(seg) << "\n";

    point_a.x = 1;
    seg = Segment(point_a, point_b); // reset
    std::cout << Distance(seg) << "\n";
}
```

I used the name Segment as per suggestion above. This style is closer to functional programming style. Segment is immutable unless you explicitly reset it with a common assignment syntax. Distance is not a member function because it can be implemented in terms of Segment's public interface.

Regards,
&rzej